# vim colors is not matching colorscheme (dracula)

Tags: macos, vim, color-scheme, iterm2, systemcolors

The first image is what it is supposed to look like, and the second one is what mine looks like. Notice that some colors that should be white is green, and some that is green is white, and the known property `prototype` which is highlighted in blue, which should be pink.

I'm using iTerm2 (3.3) on macOS Catalina, with VIM 8.1.2100.

It looks the same if I use the built in terminal. I've even tried different versions of vim, such as neovim and macvim, but all looks the same. I've tried with a clean .vimrc and only the essentials - but still looks the same.

Anyone experienced this before and knows why this is?

This is the colorscheme I'm using: https://draculatheme.com/vim/

[image: Original image]
[image: My image]

Comment: Hey Filibustr, i’m one of the dracula maintainers. Have tou tried asking on the GitHub issues list, or reading `:help dracula`? I suspect you need to disable italics. We have several duplicate issues around this, so please read there. Please self-answer if you find that this is the solution!

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks. That seemed to be the issue indeed. Didn't find anything about it on GitHub issues though, and the vim help section doesn't seem to exist for me. :/ Will post below the solution I found.

Comment: make sure to generate the helptags (`:helptags ALL`); if your dracula version is too old, you may not have the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution to the problem D. Ben Knoble wrote about. Don't know if there's an easier solution out there, but this worked for me.

https://gist.github.com/mattn/3f43125df1020fada9b6

I changed the last line to call the function instantaneously.

`call s:disable_italic()`

Comment: Oh goodness! We have a config variable for the italics. Try `:let g:dracula_italic = 0` before you load the colorscheme.